# JavaScript - Array of pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a method that, when given a number, constructs an array the length of that number. For instance:

```
var myArray = constructArray(6);
```

Now, this is the important part. The array it constructs needs to pair numbers. For instance, if I gave the number 6, the result it returns would look like this:

```
[2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

And If I gave 5:

```
[2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

If I gave 4:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Yeah, you get the point! The numbers are backwards and in pairs (when the length provided is even).

I'm creating a book in CSS and the stacking order (`z-index`) of the elements needs to follow this pattern, so that pages on top in the DOM are actually on top aesthetically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function constructArray(length){
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        result.unshift(Math.floor(i / 2));
    }    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. This is the code I used to apply your logic to the actual z-index. I just needed help with the logic:

`pages.css('z-index', function () {
   return Math.floor(pages.length / 2) - Math.ceil($(this).index() / 2);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

```
function constructArray (a) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var num = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<a;i++) {
        arr.push(num);
        if ((i-1)%2 == 0)
            num++;
    }
    return arr.reverse();
}
```

Should work :)